# Have people trained themselves to have better memory by using the "military method"?

Tags: memory

When I look up photographic memory techniques, I see a lot about a "military method". I think it's best captured [here](https://hackspirit.com/how-to-get-a-photographic-memory/):

> This method will take you at least 1 month to develop. You must also
>   practice it every day because one missed day will set you back a week.
>
> Step 1: You must be in a windowless, dark room. You need to be free
>   from distraction with only a bright lamp in the room.
>
> Step 2: Sit in a position where you have easy access to turn your
>   light on and off without getting up. Next, get a piece of paper and
>   cut a rectangular hole out of it.
>
> Step 3: Now, get whatever it is that you’re trying to memorize. Cover
>   it with the piece of paper, exposing only 1 paragraph.
>
> Then, adjust your distance from the book in a way that your eyes will
>   automatically focus on the words instantly upon opening.
>
> Step 4: Next, turn off the light and let your eyes adjust to the dark.
>   Flip the light on for a split second and then off again.
>
> By doing so, you will have a visual imprint in your eyes of the
>   material that was in front of you.
>
> Step 5: When the imprint is fading, flip the light on again for a
>   split second, while again staring at the material.
>
> Step 6: Rinse and repeat the process until you can memorize every
>   word in the paragraph.

However, I cannot find any information about the military trying this or any studies confirming that it works, much less the claim that one missed day will set you back a week.

Note that this method is also described [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Develop-a-Photographic-Memory/) and [here](https://www.mantelligence.com/how-to-develop-a-photographic-memory/).

A similar question about the validity of this method was also asked [here](https://forum.artofmemory.com/t/the-military-method-for-photographic-memory-true-or-false/29355), which includes additional links that reference this "military method".

So there are multiple independent questions:

1. Did the military, at any point, try any method similar to this?
2. If anyone (including the military) has tested this method, did it appear to work?
3. Is it true that missing one day of practicing this method generally sets one back by an entire week?

Comment: That reminds me of the "Renshawing" mentioned [Robert Heinlein's novella "Gulf."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_(novella))  It was a method to improve memory and reading speed, though, not simply to memorize a single passage.

Comment: Ha!  Finally found the real [Dr. Renshaw.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Renshaw)  This page on the "Heinlein Society" site lists all the [characters in "Gulf" by full name.](https://www.heinleinsociety.org/concordance/books/gulf_hc.htm)

Comment: Is the method described in Samuel Renshaw's Wikipedia page the one you had in mind?

Comment: The Wikipedia page just says "flashing pages", but that seems right!

Comment: This sounds like it would wreak havoc on the eyes.